# How to set load stylesheet or javascript dynamically in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

i have a global variable who hold the value for routing i need to use them to refer the stylesheet like

```
<%: Globals.routing %> but if i use them to loading stylesheet they never work prehaps the render html soemthing goes like

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%:Globals.ROOT_PATH %>jqueryui1.8.7.custom.css">
```

are their any right way to load stylehsheet by passing the location or href tag dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use global variables for this. Use URL helpers:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%: Url.Content("~/content/css/jqueryui1.8.7.custom.css") %>" />
```

Inside the `Url.Content` helper you could use some variable to specify user specific paths for the CSS.

Also make sure that the `<head>` tag doesn't have a `runat="server"` attribute or you might get some bad surprises.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/jqueryui1.8.7.custom.css") %>'  />
```